# How to fix "The import javax.xml.namespace.QName cannot be resolved" while upgrading from JDK1.8 to JDK1.11

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, namespaces

I am upgrading my java application from JDK1.8 to JDK1.11. One of the classes using import javax.xml.namespace.QName; from JDK11 is unresolvable.

Adding external jar javax.xml.1.3.4.jar and updating build path in eclipse cannot help as the parameters are not same in QName constructor. My QName has only 2 parameters which was supported by JDK1.8 and not supported in JDK11. Please answer if anybody encountered this kind of issue and unable to import javax.xml.namespace.QName.

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
class serviceIPAddress{

// Object created with 2 parameters


private final static QName SERVICENOWUSERVERIPADDRESS_QNAME = new QName("http://www.service-now.com/u_server_ip_address", "ServiceNow_u_server_ip_address");


.....
//Code follows

}
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your project or something in Eclipse. javax.xml.namespace.QName has not been removed or changed in JDK 11 so your code should compile. It is possible that you are developing a module and have forgotten to put `requires java.xml` in module-info.java? If you aren't creating a module then you may be running into an Eclipse issue. In any case, I would suggest removing javax.xml.1.3.4.jar as that will just make matters worse - you should never put JAR files on the class path that contain APIs that the Java SE / JDK provides.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Has anyone got a clear answer for this? Please suggest.